# How do you find all Users *not* in a Parse.com Query?

Tags: database, parse-platform

I have a "Logs" table that has a pointer to a User in the User table. I am trying to "Find all users without a log entry for the last N days". The following query, however, seems to return *all* users instead of the expected value.

Here is my current query:

```
var logsFrom = function(start, end) {
    // Query for all logs within the last 24 hours
    var Log = Parse.Object.extend("Log");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Log);

    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", start);
    query.lessThan("createdAt", end);
    return query;
};
var nonLogsFound = function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    // Midnight of the current day
    var end = new Date();
    end.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Midnight of the previous day
    var time = (5 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    var start = new Date(end.getTime() - (time));

    var count = 0;
    var logQuery = logsFrom(start, end);
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "user", logQuery);
    userQuery.find({
        success: function(users) {
            // This returns *all* users.
            count = users.length;
            response.success("Query complete! (" + count + " results)");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error(error);
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: is the `user` attribute on the `log` class a pointer or a string?

Comment: @hhanesand A pointer

Answer (score 0):

Your query is matching an pointer ('user') against a string ('objectId'). That is why it's returning all results.

Maybe changing

```
userQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "user", logQuery);
```

To

```
userQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "user.objectId", logQuery);
```

I'm not sure if it supports keypaths though haven't tested.